# Disable/Enable submit button and running this javascript every 1 second onload

Tags: javascript, html

I need to disable the submit button when the required fields are not filled. But the script is not working. If anybody can help, thanks in advance.

Html :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub1" id="submit1">
```

Javascript :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        function form_valid() {
        var u1=document.getElementById("#user1").value;
        var p1=document.getElementById("#pass1").value;
        var p2=document.getElementById("#pass2").value;
        var s1=document.getElementById("#school1").value;

        if ((u1 == null)&&(p1 != p2)&&(s1 == null))
        {
            document.getElementById("#submit1").disabled = true;                    
            document.getElementById("#submit1").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");  
        }
        else
            {

            document.getElementById("#submit1").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("#submit1").removeAttribute("disabled");            
            }
        }
            function form_run() {
                window.setInterval(function(){form_valid();}, 1000);
            }            
    </script>
```

Body tag (HTML) :

```
<body bgcolor="#d6ebff" onload="form_run();">
```

Comment: This approach should be avoided. It is confusing to a user as to why they cannot press the submit button. You should just check to see if all input is valid when pressing the submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var u1=document.getElementById("#user1").value;
```

**Dont use #**, you have many times in your code

```
var u1=document.getElementById("user1").value;
```

Comment: I got the result. But what's the difference if you use '#' or not? Why should it be avoided.

Comment: @Harshan01 # is used in jquery to specify the ID of element. If you use # in your code, it will look up for element whose ID is #user1.